# How to properly stop rxjava Flowable?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have the following code structure

Service

```
public Flowable entryFlow()
{
    return Flowable.fromIterable(this::getEntries)
}
```

Consumer

```
void start()
{
    disposable = service
        .entryFlow()
        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .subscribe(
            entry -> ...,
            this::onError,
            this::subscriptionFinished);
}

void stop()
{
    disposable.dispose();
}

private void onError(Throwable e)
{
    subscriptionFinished();
}

private void subscriptionFinished()
{
    //
}
```

I need a way to stop the flowable from fetching and emitting data when the stop method is called.

By doing the following, I noticed that the doOnCancel lambda is not always called.

```
void start()
{
    disposable = service
        .entryFlow()
        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .doOnCancel(this::snapshotFinished)
        .subscribe(
            entry -> ...,
            this::onError,
            this::subscriptionFinished);
}

void stop()
{
    disposable.dispose();
}
```

Alternative would be

```
volatile stopped;

void start()
{
    disposable = service
        .entryFlow()
        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .takeUntil(x -> stopped)
        .subscribe(
            entry -> ...,
            this::onError,
            this::subscriptionFinished);
}

void stop()
{
    stopped = true;
}
```

What would be the recommended implementation of start and stop such that the flowable stops emitting and onComplete or a similar method (doOnCancel action?) is called?

**Later Edit**:

To make my use-case shorter

Is is enough to call disposable.dispose to stop the flowable getting data from iterable and emitting to source? I only have 1 subscriber and need to have either onComplete/onError/other-callback called when the flowable ends regardless of cause.

By other callback I mean one of doOnCancel/doFinally etc.

Thank you

Comment: The only reason `doOnCancel` wouldn't be called if the flow already finished at that time. Why do you need to react to cancellation only? You could consider `doFinally` to react to termination and cancellation.

Comment: doFinally sounds interesting, but from the javadoc I understand that it will be called in addition onComplete / orError. 

I don't really need to know what caused the flow to end (complete, error, cancel), but I want the end action do be executed exactly once.

Comment: Added a more compact description of my question in the later edit section

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use the `dispose()` method. And then just add `doOnDispose` to trigger your side-effect-code.

Comment: is there any better approach

Comment: @Appyx there is no `doOnDipose()` for Flowable