# How do I manually cancel / dispose of an RXJava2 Flowable?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, filestack

I have an Android project that is using the [FileStack dependency](https://github.com/filestack/filestack-java) that is relying on RX Java 2. Specifically, `io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.2`. This has not really been a problem up until now as I have been unable to figure out how to specifically cancel a [Flowable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html).

I have implemented the

Here is my code below:

```
private Flowable<Progress<FileLink>> upload;

private void myMethod(){
    upload = new Client(myConfigOptionsHere)
      .uploadAsync(filePath, false, storageOptions);

        upload.doOnNext(progress -> {
                    double progressPercent = progress.getPercent();
                    if(progressPercent > 0){
                        //Updating progress here
                    }
                    if (progress.getData() != null) {
                        //Sending successful upload callback here
                    }
                })
                .doOnComplete(new Action() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() throws Exception {
                        //Logging he complete action here
                    }
                })
                .doOnCancel(new Action() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() throws Exception {
                        //Logging the cancel here
                    }
                })
                .doOnError(new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable t) throws Exception {
                        //Logging the error here
                    }
                })
                .subscribe();

}

public void cancelUpload(){
    //What do I do here to manually stop the upload Flowable? 
    //IE upload.cancel();
}
```

**What do I need to do / call against the `upload` Flowable so that I can manually trigger a cancel when the user cancels the upload via a button click?** I see people [recommending](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48929782/2480714) calling `dispose`, but I don't see that option when checking the available methods to use against the Flowable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that I was attempting to dispose of / cancel the wrong object. I adjusted my code to the following:

```
private Disposable disposable;

private void myMethod(){
    Flowable<Progress<FileLink>> upload = new Client(myConfigOptionsHere)
      .uploadAsync(filePath, false, storageOptions);

        this.disposable = upload.doOnNext(progress -> {
                    double progressPercent = progress.getPercent();
                    if(progressPercent > 0){
                        //Updating progress here
                    }
                    if (progress.getData() != null) {
                        //Sending successful upload callback here
                    }
                })
                .doOnComplete(new Action() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() throws Exception {
                        //Logging he complete action here
                    }
                })
                .doOnCancel(new Action() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() throws Exception {
                        //Logging the cancel here
                    }
                })
                .doOnError(new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable t) throws Exception {
                        //Logging the error here
                    }
                })
                .subscribe();

}

public void cancelUpload(){
    if(this.disposable != null){
        this.disposable.dispose();
        this.disposable = null;
    }
}
```

and was able to get it working just fine. Essentially you need to call the `dispose()` method against the `dispose` object, not the `Flowable`.

Thanks for the assistance / message [jschuss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8728528/jschuss)